# How to update an object inside a Mongo Document Array (at a specific index)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to let a user check off whether they've "acquired" a grocery item and update the Database.

In more concrete terms, when a user checks a box, I want to toggle a Boolean property `acquired` on an ingredient object. Ingredients are stored in an array on the `GroceryList` document:

Here is the Schema for a Grocery List

```
const GroceryListSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  createdAt         : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updatedAt         : { type: Date },
  ingredients       : { type: Array },
  recipes           : { type: Array },
  user              : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserSchema', required: true },
}
```

An ingredient looks like this:

```
{ quantity: '3',
  unit: null,
  ingredient: 'zucchinis, chopped',
  minQty: '3',
  maxQty: '3',
  acquired: false }
```

I've looked at a lot of similar questions, the Mongoose documentation and the MongoDB documentation and I've tried a ton of different versions but I'm stumped.

Frontend:

```
function toggleIngredient(elmt, groceryListId, ingrIdx) {
  $.post('/cart/grocery-list/toggleIngredient', {
    groceryListId,
    ingrIdx,
    newValue: elmt.checked, // if checkbox was checked before toggling it
  })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Backend:

```
  app.post('/cart/grocery-list/toggleIngredient', (req, res, next) => {
    const { groceryListId, ingrIdx, newValue } = req.body;

    GroceryListSchema.findById(groceryListId, (err, groceryList) => {
      if (err) return next(err);

      // if was unchecked, change to checked & vice-versa
      groceryList.ingredients[ingrIdx].acquired = newValue;

      // save updated grocery list
      groceryList.save().then((updatedList) => {
        console.log(updatedList.ingredients);
      }).catch(error => next(error));
    });
  });
```

**RESULTS / THE PROBLEM:**
When I run the code above, I successfully see 1 ingredient's `acquired` property get toggled from `false`->`true` in the callback

```
console.log(updatedList.ingredients);
```

However, the next time I fetch the grocery list, that same ingredient's `acquired = false`. This leads me to believe that the `GroceryList` document isn't actually getting updated in the database. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongoose can't track changes inside the array if you modify array element directly using its index

try adding this line before saving

```
groceryList.markModified(`ingredients.${ingrIdx}.acquired`);
```